# Showing $\int_0^{\int_0^u{\rm sech}vdv}\sec vdv\equiv u$ and $\int_0^{\int_0^u\sec vdv}{\rm sech} vdv\equiv u$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-integrals

The two following very weird-looking theorems

$$\int_0^{\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon}\sec\upsilon d\upsilon \equiv u$$

$$\int_0^{\int_0^u\sec\upsilon d\upsilon}\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon \equiv u$$

are simple consequences of the rather remarkable (in my opinion) fact that

$$\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon$$

$$\int_0^u\operatorname{sec}\upsilon d\upsilon$$

are inverse functions of each other (specifically

$$2\operatorname{atn}\exp u-\frac{\pi}{2}$$&$$\ln\tan(\frac{u}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})$$

respectively, or $\operatorname{gd}^{-1}u$ and $\operatorname{gd}u$ if the convention of using "$\operatorname{gd}$" to stand for *gudermannian* be received).

The relations between integrals of circular and hyperbolic functions, and what an extraordinarily tight 'system' they all seem to form is a constant source of fascination to me - and the *particular* relation cited here is probably the strangest of all, to my mind.

It's probably too much to expect that a *group-under-composition* of functions could be formed out of them, or anything *quite* so neat ... but anyway:

The "weird theorem" (really just one theorem, of course) that is the nominal subject of this post: can it be proven *directly* from the properties of hyperbolic and circular functions and their relations amongst each other, rather than by the crude expedient of just evaluating the integrals and simply exhibiting them as mutual inverses?

**Update**

I've just been brewing some thoughts, and I can't help thinking now that it might have something to do with the fact that

$$\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\operatorname{asech}{y}$$

&

$$\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{y^2-1}}=\operatorname{asec}{y} .$$

(I tend to use "y" in these kinds of integral, as when I was shown them the very first time it was by differentiating $y$ = *circular or hyperbolic function* of $x$ & expressing the result in terms of $y$; & I've just never gotten out of the habit.)

**@ Michael Hoppe**

Let's see ... they are effectively *compositions* so

$$\operatorname{sech}u.\operatorname{sec}\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv 1$$

$$\operatorname{sec}u.\operatorname{sech}\int_0^u\operatorname{sec}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv 1 ... $$

I think that's what they would be in differentiated form. Is there any lead in that?

$$\operatorname{sec}\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv \operatorname{cosh}u \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(\operatorname{i})$$

$$\operatorname{sech}\int_0^u\operatorname{sec}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv \operatorname{cos}u\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(\operatorname{ii})$$

they certainly look less formidable in that form.

Manipulating

$$\operatorname{sech}{u} + i \operatorname{tanh}{u} = \exp{\left [i \arctan{\left ( \sinh{u} \right )} \right ]}$$

a little, we get

$$\operatorname{sech}u =\operatorname{cos}\operatorname{atn}\operatorname{sinh}u\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(\operatorname{iii})$$

$$\operatorname{sec}u =\operatorname{cosh}\operatorname{asinh}\operatorname{tan}u\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(\operatorname{iv})$$

Replacing $\operatorname{sec}()$ in (i) with its identity in (iv), & $\operatorname{sech}()$ in (ii) with its identity in (iii), we get

$$\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv \operatorname{atn}\operatorname{sinh}u$$

$$\int_0^u\operatorname{sec}\upsilon d\upsilon\equiv \operatorname{asinh}\operatorname{tan}u$$

Looks a bit like going round in circles. No, it's not quite that - it's more like tracing the threads allover the place & observing how wonderfully they join up end-to-end, no matter how crazy an excursion they make. well it does show that the functions in question are indeed inverses - *but* - we have still done it by solving the integrals ... *really*. Is this an improvement? I'm not sure. But I have certainly tried to incorporate the various advice that the contibutors have most graciously dispensed. And we've gotten another rather curioferous theorem into the bargain.

$$\operatorname{sech}{u} + i \operatorname{tanh}{u} = \exp{\left [i\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}{\upsilon.d\upsilon} \right ]}$$

$$\operatorname{sech}{u}= \cos{\left [\int_0^u\operatorname{sech}{\upsilon.d\upsilon} \right ]}$$

$$\operatorname{sec}{u}= \cosh{\left [\int_0^u\operatorname{sec}{\upsilon.d\upsilon} \right ]}$$

And it's also *quite* possible that I've missed the point or lost the plot somewhere along the line!

Nor have I forgotten my line of thought either - the way that if you integrate

$$\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

and the range of integration straddles the point $y=1$, it's beautifully incorporated by $1/i = -i$ going outside; and the $\operatorname{asec}$ function 'splices' onto the $\operatorname{asech}$ - as both have a √ singularity at that point - & turns through a right-angle.

Comment: Very interesting and would be intriguing to look at other pairs too.

Comment: You see what I mean then - like in other branches of mathematics - linear algebra being fertile ground for this kind of thing - you prove a theorem not by _unpacking the content_ of whatever items it might be that you wish to relate, but by examining the _patterns & structures_ that such items form when taken together as an ensemble. To me that theorem that I have cited here looks _for all the world_ like something that ought to be showable to proceed _in its own right_ from the very _recipe itself_ for circular & hyperbolic functions.

Comment: I think, more to the point, the reason this holds is that $$\operatorname{sech}{u} + i \operatorname{tanh}{u} = \exp{\left [i \arctan{\left ( \sinh{u} \right )} \right ]}$$

Comment: @Ron Gordon -- I'm getting the hang of this site! I first thought "why on ___earth___ did you use _LateX_ notation in a field in which it isn't interpreted!!?" ... then I had the _brilliant __brilliant___ idea, which I'm sure _no-one_ has ever thought of before, of copying the text, pasting it into an _answer_ field, and summoning a preview!! Thanks for that contribution. I'll examine it ... but I was actually brewing some thoughts of my own that I was actually just about to send in. I'll put it as an edit to the original question ... I get that prerogative, it being my question!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: yeah, that's what I do and did here.

Comment: Oh there'll be _loads_ of little tricks I've  yet to learn - I have _no_ doubt atall!

Comment: Have you tried to show that their derivatives are equal?

Comment: I've put something at the end of the original post.

Comment: I've added a bit more. It gets a bit rambling, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've always loved the Gudermannian function. The least mystifying way to start any discussion of it is to note that the functions $f(t):=\frac{2t}{1-t^2},\,g(t):=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ satisfy not only $f(\tan\tfrac{x}{2})=\sin x,\,g(\tan\tfrac{x}{2})=\cos x$, but also $f(\tanh\tfrac{x}{2})=\tanh x,\,g(\tanh\tfrac{x}{2})=\operatorname{sech}x$. From this it follows that the definition $\operatorname{gd}x:=2\arctan\tanh\frac{x}{2}$ satisfies results such as $\tan\tfrac{\operatorname{gd}x}{2}=\tanh\frac{x}{2},\,\sin \operatorname{gd}x=\tanh x$ etc.

Now for the integrals. Note that $\tfrac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\operatorname{gd}x=\frac{\operatorname{sech}^2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tanh^2\frac{x}{2}}=\operatorname{sech}x$. But to go from the Gudermannian to its inverse, all I have to do is swap the two kinds of "tangent". So look what happens to the derivative: $$\tfrac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\operatorname{gd}^{-1}x=\frac{\sec^2\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}=\sec x.$$You know that sign difference when you compare $1=\cos^2\tfrac{x}{2}+\sin^2\tfrac{x}{2}$ to $1=\cosh^2\tfrac{x}{2}-\sinh^2\tfrac{x}{2}$, or $\cos x=\cos^2\tfrac{x}{2}-\sin^2\tfrac{x}{2}$ to $\cosh x=\cosh^2\tfrac{x}{2}+\sinh^2\tfrac{x}{2}$? It perfectly balances the sign difference when comparing $y=\tan x\implies y'=1+y^2$ to $y=\tanh x\implies y'=1-y^2$, i.e. comparing $\tfrac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\tan x=\tfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ to $\tfrac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\tanh x=\tfrac{1}{1-x^2}$. In fact, it *causes* that result about derivatives.

Comment: It's a kind of dense vast _web_ of symmetries; and there's probably prettymuch unlimited scope for spinning new threads. I sometimes wonder whether some kind of algebraic _structure_ could be forged out of it - something a bit like a _group_ maybe. I'll leave _actually doing_ that to the serious heavyweights, though ... if they think there's any mileage in it _atall_! And the _gudermannian_ function ... it is _lovable_! ... and people are looking at a depiction of it all over the place & every day in the _Mercator projection_. Another one I recently discovered is _sl_ - _sn_ for k=i.

Comment: @AmbrettrOrrisey The inverse is called the Lambertian in the context of Mercator projection. Proving its conjectured value was a major unsolved problem in the mid-16th century. Of course, is they'd known the FTC, then it would have been trivial. I've always been disappointed no-one seems to have access to the very first proof of the integral from 1668.

Comment: Sometimes in these archaic proofs they effectively _do use_ integral calculus without actually _broaching_ it explicitly as a particular reasoning process in it's own right. This is so in the case of the proof by ... was it Archimedes? o gf

Comment: of the formula for the volume of a a sphere, with the 4/3 factor entering in. ¶ I didn't know the inverse of the Gudermannian was _canonised_ & named after Lambert (who of course was a cartographer, there being a few projections named after him ... assuming it's the same Lambert, which is pretty safe, I think!). Yep thanks for that instruction. For sure, it was hard work in those days, without the differential & integral calculus!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to arrive at *some degree* of generalisation of this - infact through that observation that $\operatorname{asech}$ & $\operatorname{asec}$ are both integrals of 'complementary' functions - complementary in the sense of having occurences of $1-x$ replaced with $x-1$ as the point $x=1$ is traversed. An observation that has arisen through this little exercise is that say we have a function $\operatorname{f}$, and we integrate it to get the primitive of $\operatorname{f}$, say $\operatorname{g}$, and then we take the inverse of that, say $\operatorname{ag}$, and integrate *that*, it is actually equivalent to integrating $\operatorname{f}$ multiplied by the ordinate. This is easy to see on a graph: the integral just described is the area enclosed under the curve cut-off by the horizontal line joining (0, $\operatorname{f}(x)$) to ($x$, $\operatorname{f}(x)$), which is

$$\int x.d(g(x)) = \int xf(x).dx .$$

. In this particular case and considering $0\leq x\leq 1$, we have

$$\int_1^x\frac{d\upsilon}{\upsilon\sqrt{1-\upsilon^2}}=\operatorname{asech}(x), $$

and

$$\int_1^x\frac{d\upsilon}{\sqrt{1-\upsilon^2}}=\operatorname{acos}(x), $$

and (using $y$, to emphasise that we are switching to viewlng the integration along the $y$ axis)

$$\int_0^y\operatorname{sech}\upsilon.d\upsilon=\operatorname{acos}x=\operatorname{acos}(\operatorname{sech}y) ,$$

which is indeed one of the formulæ arrived at in the main body of the question.

Likewise for $x\geq 1$ we have

$$\int_1^x\frac{d\upsilon}{\upsilon\sqrt{\upsilon^2-1}}=\operatorname{asec}(x), $$

and

$$\int_1^x\frac{d\upsilon}{\sqrt{\upsilon^2-1}}=\operatorname{acosh}(x), $$

and (using $y$, to emphasise ... again)

$$\int_0^y\operatorname{sec}\upsilon.d\upsilon=\operatorname{acosh}x=\operatorname{acosh}(\operatorname{sec}y) ,$$

Which is the *corresponding* formula arrived at in the main body.

It can be seen with a little consideration that the *being inverses of each other* of the two integrals in $y$ hinges on its being so that the functions

$$\operatorname{acosh} \& \operatorname{asech}$$

are functions $\operatorname{\phi} \& \operatorname{\psi}$ such that

$$\operatorname{\phi}(x)\equiv\operatorname{\psi}(1/x) ;$$

and likewise for

$$\operatorname{acos} \& \operatorname{asec} .$$

Translating this into terms of the *origin* of these functions as integrals of

$$\operatorname{f_l}(x)\equiv\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} \&$$

$$\operatorname{f_r}(x)\equiv\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}, $$

(l=*left* & b=*right*), that which is what it *hinges* on is that

$$\operatorname{f_a}(x).dx\equiv (1/x)\operatorname{f_b}(1/x) \&$$

$$\operatorname{f_a}(1/x).d(1/x)\equiv x\operatorname{f_b}(x), $$

where a=l or r & b=r or l. This is very fiddly to put into symbols: but basically what it hinges on is that if $1/x$ be substituted for $x$ in $\operatorname{f_l}.dx$ then $x.\operatorname{f_r}.dx$ should be obtained; if $1/x$ be substituted for $x$ in $x.\operatorname{f_l}.dx$ then $\operatorname{f_r}.dx$ should be obtained; if $1/x$ be substituted for $x$ in $\operatorname{f_r}.dx$ then $x.\operatorname{f_l}.dx$ should be obtained; if $1/x$ be substituted for $x$ in $x.\operatorname{f_r}.dx$ then $\operatorname{f_l}.dx$ should be obtained: basically just thorough *reciprocity* under those transformations.

It can also be seen that this happens if the function $\operatorname{f}$ is of the form *reciprocal of* ($x$×function that changes $1-x$ into $x-1$ or $x-1$ into $1-x$ when $1/x$ is substituted for $x$ and it is multiplied by $x$ from $d(1/x)=-dx/x^2$). As I said, this is *terribly* fiddly to put into words & symbols; but the underlying idea is really quite an elementary one.

So we could construct pairs of functions of the following form:

$$\frac{1}{x((1-x)^k.(1+x)^{n-k})^{1/n}}  $$

&

$$\frac{1}{x((x-1)^k.(1+x)^{n-k})^{1/n}} ,$$
where $n$ is a natural number, and $k$ is one of the *Euler totient set* of $n$; and the functions obtained by taking the primitives of these ought to have this *reciprocal property* we have been discussing of the integrals of their inverses being *mutual* inverses.

It actually works beautifully for the case n=1, even though that results in integrals that have infinities; and it's clear that it works for n=2, as that is the case that prompted this post in the first place. As for higher values of n ... anything > 2 results in thoroughly diabolickal hypergeometric functions that have *who-knows-what* inverses, and I shall have to feed them into some kind of *mathematics package* to test them for this property. It's actually not so bad though for *mutual* inverses (a bit like it's not so bad testing whether two numbers are *coprime*): you don't have to actually compute the inverses - you can just feed one into the other as an argument & see whether the identity function drops out.

For n=1, the pair is

$$-\ln(e^{-y}+1)$$

&

$$-\ln(e^{-y}-1) .$$

The former is from

$$\frac{-1}{x(1-x)}$$

... integral ...

$$\ln\frac{1-x}{x}$$

... inverse ...

$$\frac{1}{1+e^y}$$

... integral ...

$$-\ln(e^{-y}+1) ;$$

& the latter from

$$\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$$

... integral ...

$$\ln\frac{x-1}{x}$$

... inverse ...

$$\frac{1}{1-e^y}$$

... integral ...

$$-\ln(e^{-y}-1) .$$

This isn't *as much* of a generalisation as I was hoping for; but it does at least exhibit the original pair of functions being queried as being part of *some* kind of pattern, and not just an isolated special case that *just happens* to have that property *because it **does***!

The functions gotten in $n=1$ régime are worthy of some comment, I think, on various grounds. For one thing, it will be observed that in this case $\operatorname{f_l} \& \operatorname{f_r}$ are not actually different *atall*! However ... the *integrals are* different functions. And also we get infinities in this case, but fortunately it *doesn't* foil the reasoning. If we look at the whole matter *graphically*, we see that in our familiar $n=2$ case, the two integrals $\operatorname{g_l} \& \operatorname{g_r}$ *spring from* the point (1,0) square-root-wise; whereas the functions under $n=1$ proceed asymptotically from (1, -∞); and for $n>1$ they will proceed from the point (1,0) with behaviour *tending to* linearity - *^1-1/n*, to be more precise - so the vertical & then *curving down* section will get progressively tighter with increasing $n$. This brings to the next point: the functions for $n=1$ positively *abound* in negativity; normally I would want to *translate* the whole affair into a region better-populated by *positive* numbers ... but I think in this case they are better left as they are, as they better-exhibit that *continuity & progression* of behaviour just described. It applies also to the functions that constitute the final result: like *any* bona-fide self-respecting mutual inverses they ought to be *mutual refections* in the line $x=y$; in the $n=2$ case they spring from *the  origin* & 'splay-out' to become asypmtotic one to the line $x=\pi/2$ the other to the line $y=\pi/2$, whereas in $n=1$ case they approach *asymptotically* from (-∞, -∞) along the negative branch of the identity-function graph, and splay-out to become asymptotic, one to the $x$-axis, the other to the $y$, on the *negative faces* of them: this might incur that most of the affair is in terms of negative numbers ... but it the better shows that *continuity of evolution of behaviour* with increasing $n$.

**Images for Case $n=2$** (the original subject of the post)

[image][image]

The upper diagram shows the functions $y=\operatorname{asech}x$ & $y=\operatorname{asec}x$, and the lower the integrals of these along the $y$-axis $x=\operatorname{acos}\operatorname{sech}y$ & $x=\operatorname{acosh}\operatorname{sec}y$.

**Images for Case $n=1$**

[image]
[image]

The upper diagram shows the functions $y=\operatorname{ln}((1-x)/x)$ & $y=\operatorname{ln}((x-1)/x)$, and the lower the integrals of these along the $y$-axis $x=-\operatorname{ln}(e^{-y}+1)$ & $x=-\operatorname{ln}(e^{-y}-1)$.